# Best practice to implement globalization in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization, resource-files, jquery-globalization, displayname-attribute

For form labels and alert messages which are client side, using resource file is heavy or not ? Shall I need separate implementation for client side specific strings using jquery and resource file for server side messages. Please let me know the best practice on performance point of view.

Comment: See [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32764989)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at these articles that explains globalization perfectly with sample code:

[ASP.NET MVC 5 Internationalization](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx)

[ASP.NET MVC 3 Internationalization - Part 2 (NerdDinner)](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-part-2.aspx)

[ASP.NET MVC 5 Internationalization · Date and Time](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-date-time.aspx)

[ASP.NET MVC 5 Internationalization · How to Store Strings in a Database or Xml](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-store-strings-in-database-or-xml.aspx)

Comment: I know different methods. But I need to make a comparison whether we need to go for server side resource file implementation or use client side jquery language plugin. What is the performance cost on using resource file.